# Usage of select with include_subdirs and module in subdirectory

Tags: ocaml-dune

Consider the following file structure in a dune project:

```
...
src/
|
+-- analysis/
    |
    +-- file.mli
    |
    +-- file.enabled.ml
    |
    +-- file.disabled.ml
```

That is, I have an `src` folder with an `analysis` subfolder containing two versions of the File module, plus its interface. The choice depends on whether package `ocamlgraph` is available. Therefore, I tried the following stanza in `src/dune`:

```
(library
 (name test)
 (libraries
  (select analysis/file.ml from
   (ocamlgraph -> analysis/file.enabled.ml)
   (  -> analysis/file.disabled.ml)
  )
 )
)
(include_subdirs unqualified)
```

However, this fails with:

```
Error: Some modules don't have an implementation.
You need to add the following field to this stanza:

  (modules_without_implementation file)
```

The suggestion does not work in my case (the modules *do* have an implementation, it's just that Dune couldn't find it). If I add it, I get:

```
Error: test__Analysis/file corresponds to an invalid module name
-> required by _build/default/src/test.ml-gen
```

The real issue seems to be that apparently Dune ignores the `analysis/` from the first part of the `select` stanza? I then tried removing it:

```
(library
 (name test)
 (libraries
  (select file.ml from
   (ocamlgraph -> analysis/file.enabled.ml)
   (  -> analysis/file.disabled.ml)
  )
 )
)
(include_subdirs unqualified)
```

But now, `dune build` fails with:

```
File "src/dune", line 5, characters 18-42:
5 |    (ocamlgraph -> analysis/file.enabled.ml)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: The format for files in this select branch must be file.{name}.ml
```

Of course, if I remove the `analysis/` everywhere, it doesn't work. Either because `file.mli` is still in `analysis`, thus causing:

```
Error: Module "File" appears in several directories:
- _build/default/src
- _build/default/src/analysis
This is not allowed, please rename one of them.
```

Or, if I move it to `src`, the error is, as expected:

```
Error: No rule found for src/file.enabled.ml
```

Since, of course, `src/file.enabled.ml` does not exist.

The only way I can make Dune work is to **remove** the `analysis` directory altogether, flattening out the structure (which I want to avoid). But it seems like it should be possible to use `select` even in the presence of file names with subdirectories. Is it possible? If so, how?

##### Reproduction script

In case it helps, here's a script to quickly test changes to the `dune` file.

```
dune init project proj
cd proj
mkdir -p src/analysis
echo "val f : int -> int" > src/analysis/file.mli
echo "let f i = i + 1" > src/analysis/file.enabled.ml
echo "let f _i = 0" > src/analysis/file.disabled.ml
cat >src/dune <<EOF
(library
 (name test)
 (libraries
  (select analysis/file.ml from
   (ocamlgraph -> analysis/file.enabled.ml)
   (  -> analysis/file.disabled.ml)
  )
 )
)
(include_subdirs unqualified)
EOF
dune build
```